publish book created with markdown to bookdown.org
I successfully rendered a book in my RStudio IDE (built using bookdown) as suggested by @yihui-xie
bookdown::render_book(new_session = TRUE)

But when I wanted to publish,
bookdown::publish_book(account = 'drki_musa')

I received this message:
> bookdown::publish_book(account = 'drki_musa')
── Preparing for deployment ──────────────────────────────────
Error in `deployApp()`:
! Can't find any accounts with `account` =
  "drki_musa".
ℹ Available account names: "drkim".

I have connected my Gmail and given access to Bookdown. My Bookdown username is drkim_musa. I remember the last time I successfully published to Bookdown (2 years ago); those lines of code worked. See the link here.
So next, I checked the Global Option in RStudio IDE. I could see my other Posit Connect (drkim) account but not the Bookdown account (drki_musa). Should I add Posit Connect URL for Bookdown here?


Try the following:
bookdown::publish_book(account = 'drkim')

I can't use that account name because it does not belong to Bookdown but to a different connect server instead.

Authors must establish a connection between RStudio and Bookdown before deploying a book generated by the bookdown package to the Bookdown website.
To do so,

Go To Global Option in your RStudio
Click Publishing
Click Connect
Choose Posit Connect
Enter bookdown.org in the URL


Then you will see this
Global Option -> Publishing

Now, you can start deploying your book by running these 2 lines of code. In this example, my Bookdown username is drki_musa
bookdown::render_book(new_session = TRUE)
 bookdown::publish_book(account = 'drki_musa)
`
